# ¿Cómo puedo capturar la confirmación de lectura de correo MVC core c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, eventos, microsoft-graph

Envió un correo por c# y solicitud la confirmación de lectura, esta llega de forma correcta al correo indicado, pero necesito recibirlo en mi códigoCo.

Comment: Pega tu código como texto en la pregunta una vez editada. Así la gente tendrá mejor perspectiva para poder ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: Dale una mirada a [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), así será más fácil que puedas obtener respuestas a tus preguntas.